# Get Icon WPF code not working on CD-ROM

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, icons, cd-rom

This is pretty standard code:

```
 public static System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource GetIcon(string Path, int Width = 256, int Height = 256)
    {
        IShellItem ppsi = null;
        IntPtr hbitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        Guid uuid = new Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe");

        SHCreateItemFromParsingName(Path, IntPtr.Zero, uuid, ref ppsi);
        ((IShellItemImageFactory)ppsi).GetImage(new SIZE(Width, Height), SIIGBF.SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT, ref hbitmap);
        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbitmap, IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
```

It works all the time except when trying to see icons (notably WMV) icons on a CD-ROM.  Does it need more time to download?  Or something... The Bitmapsource object does have a 'downloading' event.  But I've stepped through the code and that is not being hit.

It seems this could also be a 'caching' issue.  But oddly only affecting the CD-Rom icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I even paid a guy to help me on one of those sites that you can get an expert.  We worked together for a while and couldn't find a good solution.

Finally we found that the 'Shell-API' would report a GDI+ error anytime it couldn't write to the protected drive.  (That was my nearest guess anyway.)  So the 'imperfect' solution I came up with is this:  BTW... This does not use WPF.

```
        string tempfile = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), Path.GetExtension(filename));
        File.Copy(filename, tempfile);
        IShellItem2 ppsi = null;
        IntPtr hbitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        // GUID of IShellItem.
        Guid uuid = new Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe");
        ShellHelper.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(tempfile, IntPtr.Zero, ref uuid, out ppsi);
        ((IShellItemImageFactory)ppsi).GetImage(new SIZE(cx, cx), 0x0, out hbitmap);
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hbitmap);
        return result;
```

So I just move the file into a Temp-File.  Then I use the 'WinAPI-Shell-Factory' to get the Thumbnail from it.  Boom it works.  It's slow, but getting an icon off a CD-Rom is always slow.

Note: I tried to do a 'File-Delete' in this procedure.  But that blew-up... You may have to wait until the user logs out for these temp-files to disappear.